# Activity componnent messed up when handling configuration Changes myself

Tags: android

I added this code in my activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        setContentView(R.layout.activityView);

}
```

And also added this line in the Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

The activity is not restarting, but the layout is not correctly loaded : not all componnent are showing and buttons click listner is never called ...

I'm using the same name file for all the layouts. but different content depending on orientation.

I even tried with different names : activityView_port/activityView_land and changed the code to:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activityView_port);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activityView_land);
    }
}
```

but nothing is working ...

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why you have to control the orientation change manually? Is some reason for you do that?

Comment: I'm doing many initialisation and heavy tasks on activity creation,  hence i don't want this to be done every time the orientation is changed ... And I need the layout to be updated depending on the orientation  @LuizFernandoSalvaterra

Answer (score 0):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activityView_land);
```

> please dont call above method on configuration change. instead you can try with use some flag for determine what layout has to be set and call `reCreate()` method.

```
If don't want to destroy the current instance, better you can try removing and adding of views with animation.
```

Comment: reCreate() method will destroy the current instance of my activity and create a new one. I just want to refresh the layout while keeping the same instance ... @Sush